# CakePhp : How to avoid too many writes to the DB for a constantly updating value

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am new to PHP (and CakePHP & web development in general) and am currently trying to build a parking management application.

In brief, I have a table that is indexed with the Parking space ID and it contains the current occupancy number i.e. how many slots are in use.

When a car enters the parking lot, I want to increment this number and vice versa when the car leaves.

This is one of the 5-7 things I have to do when a car enters the parking lot.

The issue is I am thinking (maybe too early to think this?) that updating the table(writing to db) at every entry/exit would be too inefficient.

A trivial C++ implementation would be to maintain this as in-memory two dimensional array and register signal handlers to write the array to the db if and when the binary dies.

Is this possible in CakePHP? Is my efficiency concern even legitimate at this early stage of implementation?

Please advise.

Comment: Nice question but I think database is the only safe solution for this

Comment: Yes it is too early for that, optimization comes last, not first!

Comment: @mark Thanks. I agree. However, I just wanted to be sure that if there is a way that I can incorporate now rather than do a big design change later.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is recommended to [first make it work, *then* make it right, and, *finally*, make it fast](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast)

For step 3 I would suggest looking at the following factors:

- What operations need to be fast (and what means fast in this context)? (not only SQL, more a method or service)
- Am I meeting the given performance values? (e.g. Request Times, CPU Load...)
- How can I optimize the behaviour where I *need* to? (Caching, SQL Optimization, configuration etc)
- Which is the most efficient and effective way to achieve this? Does it pay out (Costs vs Profit)?

Technically speaking I would consider the following:

- The increment/decrement should be atomic or in a transaction to avoid dirty reads
- Consider that indexes (generally) reduce speed of insert (and might on update)
- Consider that an update searches for the row first (hopefully by index) and then changes the row
- Maybe it it faster to write along a "log-like" table depending on the number of SELECTs
- Try to avoid recursive requests in CakePHP from the beginning
- A redis cache can easily be set up together with CakePHP and might speed up your application
- For CakePHP optimization in general mark wrote a [good blog post](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/13/what-really-speeds-up-your-cakephp-app/) on this issue.